# Webmin alternative that installs & runs on the client machine & communicate via SSH

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ssh, webmin

Are there any Webmin alternatives that don't consume server resources but instead install on client machine & communicate via SSH client. So effectively all the actions made on that GUI are converted to terminal commands & executed via SSH. Are there any tools like that to communicate to a remote ubuntu server ?

Comment: what action you want to perform ? we can do all things via command line

Comment: yes ofcourse but for newbie or even experts it sometimes faster to do the things via GUI

Comment: I'm not aware of any alternatives, but if you want to use Webmin, then I would suggest connecting via SSH initially to start webmin, do whatever management you need to do, and then stop the service and disconnect your SSH session. That way Webmin will not constantly run.